# Having issue with nav navbar-nav in bootstrap?

Tags: menu, responsive

I am trying to create a responsive menu, I am not sure my navbar-nav function is working well or not,This is the first time creating,responsive menu.I created the class navbar-nav and uploaded to server and checked with tablet, mobiles, both giving same result,according to the device not changed.[please visit the site](http://smclothingg.com/te/). Waiting for answer, how to change the below code for responsive menu and proper guidance .

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="image/logo.png" alt="Lotus Groups"/>
    Lotus Groups</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right"> 
    <li><a href="#">Lotus Construction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lotus Interior</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lotus Digital</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lotus Property</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lotus Site</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>






 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/2L69bkwo/69/)

```
 Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that 
 appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size 
 increases. 
 It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as 
 powerful 
 mixins for generating more semantic layouts.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the css also, so that we can see what is in the class navbar-nav

Edit:

Try adding

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

to the header and if that doesnt work,

Have a look at this tutorial

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: I am using cdn libraries, updated in question and given link or else please give me the responsive code above one, I am new for bootstrap and unable to move further,

Comment: have a look at the  link I added in the answer

Comment: I am sorry, I read that , I am not sure, I am learnt and implemented correctly so will you write and post the answer so that I can get better visibility of responsive menu. I want to write for the above code and test with online now, using mobile,tablet, once again for above code

Comment: Try the answer that @kondal gave

Comment: i uploaded to server please check http://smclothingg.com/te/ in mobile and tablet? and educate me

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">
                <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" style="">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><img href="#"><img src="image/logo.png" alt="Lotus Groups"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lotus Construction</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lotus Interior</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lotus Digital</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lotus Property</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lotus Site</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
</div></div>
        </div>


</body>
```

I put your image in a li tag to include it in the navbar so on mobile the image won't go on your different menus.
The div tag with class="navbar-header" is here to dispplay a toggle button when screen is to small

EDIT:
I have added a line in your head tag, just add it please.
I've also deleted your first div class container.
It should now work !

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your answer to include a summary of what you changed and why your code works.

Comment: I uploaded valentin gachod code to server, kindly check in mobile and tablet,  have  we implemented correctly. I fixed in my mind like normal 1000px website (margin auto) both left and right side we need space so that only i kept my header like this , but ensure it should work in responsive mode, check now valentin. http://smclothingg.com/te/

Comment: hi valentin, but in mobile the menu  are coming as it is not in toggle way, please check

Comment: thanksyes it is showing now, please check valentin, but it is showing very close to left side, please check in mobile and tablet, how to make it center one

Comment: You want to center the displayed menu when the toggle button is pressed ?